# C++ pointers: Compiles correctly despite type error

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am new to C++ and currently self-learning from some [lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/lecture-notes/). In assignment 2, section 7.2, I am supposed to:

**Write a function that swaps two integer values using pointers**

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *(a);
    *(a) = *(b);
    *(b) = temp;
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    swap(a,b); // how is this not a compiler error?
    // swap(&a,&b); // this seems most correct
    cout << a << b << '\n'; // 21
    cout << &a << &b << '\n'; // addresses of a and b
    // cout << *a << *b << '\n'; // obviously doesn't compile
    return 0;
}
```

**My question**

How is `swap(a,b)` not a compiler error? In my (limited) understanding, you have to pass a pointer for the code to compile, as in `swap(&a,&b)`.

Thank you.

Comment: You are using `std::swap`, which you imported into the global namespace, not your own `swap`. Pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you! @churill . Just changed the name of my function and this is obvious.

Comment: Another good reason for not `using namespace std`.

Comment: @churill Indeed it is.

Comment: Alright, @LouisGo. So should I just use ```std::cout``` etc every time? Or is there a way to import individual functions from ```std```? Sorry if this seems trivial, but I have a python background.

Comment: @BenjaminWang `using std::cout` should be good enough.